# PHP function to create string chunks of increasing lengths ("fd6eg3" => "f", "fd", "fd6", "fd6eg3")

Tags: php, string

***tl;dr**: To store files under a path determined by their hash, I need a single function to get the following with `level=3` and `hash='fd6eg3'`: `f/fd/fd6/fd6eg3`*

I am looking for a way to create chunks (of a given string) of increasing lengths, from the beginning of the string. Also, I want to limit the number of produced chunks.

The goal is to store a file named `fd6eg3` under (with a number of chunks set to 3):

- A directory named `fd6`.
- Which is the child of a directory named `fd`.
- Which is the child of a directory named `f`.

So the final path would be: `f/fd/fd6/fd6eg3`

The closest I got is getting the "directory part" (`f/fd/fd6/`) using the following function:

```
function computePathForHash(string $hash, int $level): string
{
    if ($level <= 0) {
        return '';
    } else {
        return computePathForHash($hash, $level - 1)
            . mb_substr($hash, 0, $level)
            . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR
        ;
    }
}
echo computePathForHash('fd6eg3', 3);
```

Which output is resumed in this table:

| `level` | Returned |
| --- | --- |
| `0` | `""` |
| `1` | `"f/"` |
| `2` | `"f/fd/"` |
| `3` | `"f/fd/fd6/"` |

But I fail to add the "file part" (`$hash`) to the end.

I would like to avoid passing a third parameter such as `$initial_level` that would store the originally asked level against I could compare current `$level` to decide when to add `$hash`.

Considering the low value of `$level` (shouldn't be higher than 10 in my use case) I don't think there are arguments against recursion. I find recursion simpler to read/understand but if it's impossible in recursion I'll go with something else (or use 2 functions, one for directory part, the other to concatenate it with file part).

Comment: With level 0 just `fd6eg3` should be returned?

Comment: @user3783243 With this recursion, it's actually building the string, starting from the right.  So, if `0` returned the full string, it would be at the beginning of the result, not the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think recursion is great in the right circumstances, but a straightforward `for` loop can do this and hopefully more maintainable.

Just loop up to the level and add the start chunk of the hash each time, then add the full hash on the return...

```
function computePathForHash(string $hash, int $level): string
{
    $output = '';
    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $level; $i++ )  {
        $output .= mb_substr($hash, 0, $i) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    
    return $output . $hash;
}
```

Comment: After trying several other ways around recursion I guess I was chasing something that's not possible :) for-loop it is then!
Side note: I added a slight limit to the number of iteration based on $hash length: `$actual_level = min($level, mb_strlen($hash) - 1);` and using `$actual_level` instead of `$level` in the for-loop condition.